# select condition with provided array clauses

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to construct such a query where I have multiple postgres arrays with the same size and I would like to use it in sql where clause.
I have `condition1` and `condition2` arrays  I am trying to select all rows where one row meets `condition1[0]` and `condition2[0]` another one meets `condition1[1]` and `condition2[1]`

In another word it could be rewritten as

```
select * from table1 where 
(col1=condition1[0] and col2=condition2[0])
OR (col1=condition1[1] and col2=condition2[1])
OR (col1=condition1[2] and col2=condition2[2])
```

Array can be arbitrary size in the order of few thousands. What is the right way of constructing such query.

Comment: Sounds like a bad data model, particularly with such large arrays. Normalize!

Comment: you mean this? `SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE array[col1,col2] <@ array['foo','bar'];` (total overlap) or `SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE array[col1,col2] && array['foo','bar'];` (partial overlap)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Your_table_name
WHERE
    Array(col1)= ANY (col2) OR Array(col2) = ANY(col1);
```